# Protect Admin REST API of SyncGateway

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway

I have an application will request Sync gateway through Admin REST API. So it’s possible to configure the sync gateway to use the client credentials grant flow to request Admin API?

My application and sync gateway are in different network.

The implementation look like this:

. Resource Owner : My application

. Resource Server : Sync Gateway

. Client Application : My application

. Authorization Server : my IDP server

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sync gateway admin rest API does not need any credentials to access as long as your client know the host or ipaddress of the sync gateway, client should be able to request admin API and client application network should be able to reach the network which sync gateway is hosted